# How to create a custom plugin with root injection in Nuxt with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

**Problem**

I am trying to make a custom plugin in my Nuxt TS app. I tried following the Nuxt TS cookbook, but I seem to get a runtime error stating that my custom made function does not exist. I am relatively new to Nuxt and typescript and was hoping someone could help me explain why my function is not being recognized.
The compiler shows no errors and when working on it, ts recognizes the function:
[when you hover over the function it is correctly typed and recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OewoB.png)

**error**

TypeError: this.$getAgeGroup is not a function

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "~/plugins/ageGroups.ts"
  ],
}
```

**plugins/ageGroups.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const ageGroups = [
  'zeros',
  'teens',
  'twenties',
  'thirties',
  'fourties',
  'fifties',
  'sixties',
  'seventees',
  'eigthies',
  'nineties',
  'hundreds',
  'hundred-tens',
  'hundred-twenties',
] as const;

function getAgeGroup(val: number = 0) {
  if (val < 10) return ageGroups[0];
  if (val > 120) return ageGroups[11];
  val = Math.floor(val / 10);
  return ageGroups[val];
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $getAgeGroup(val: number): typeof ageGroups[number],
  }
}

Vue.prototype.$getAgeGroup = (val: number = 0) => getAgeGroup(val);
```

**components/ResultOverview.vue**

```
export default Vue.extend({
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$getAgeGroup(20));
  },
    ...
```

Any advice/tips would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The problem is at runtime and not specific to TS. You may want to check how custom plugins are written https://nuxtjs.org/examples/plugins-custom . They do not modify Vue.prototype explicitly.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

I am afraid I still don't fully understand the problem though; I was under the impression that https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/plugins/ was the correct way to write custom plugins when using nuxt with ts  ('@nuxt/typescript-build').

Did I misunderstand this and need to rewrite plugins/ageGroups.ts according to https://nuxtjs.org/examples/plugins-custom  ?